# partx: /dev/sdd: error adding partition 1

Tags: centos7, partition

I'm wanting to add a Swap partition to a CentOS 7 machine (running in VirtualBox). 
However, when I try and add it I get this error:

```
partx -a /dev/sdd1
partx: /dev/sdd: error adding partition 1
```

Here's the output of `fdisk /dev/sdd`

```
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdd: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1b359154

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1            2048     4196351     2097152   83  Linux
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't add a partition that already exists!

Comment: Groan - why doesn't the error output simply say that?!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to load the nbd module with `max_part` parameter:

```
modprobe nbd max_part=16
```

It fixed this issue for me.

[Reference](https://github.com/FastVPSEestiOu/ploop_userspace/issues/16)

Comment: While this answer obviously does not relate to the OP's problem, it has helped me a lot.